Faster rotation in build than the editor in Unity
I have this code for rotating the player and camera and when I build the game the rotation is faster.
I guess that’s because of the Time.deltatime multiplication but when I don’t multiply the values with the deltatime I get a slower rotation with the controller in the build (although the _rotationVelocity value is the same in the build and the editor).
Do you know if I should multiply with deltatime or not? and if I don't, why the rotation isn't consistent in both the joystick and mouse inputs? Thanks :)
Here is the code:
private void HandleRotation()
    {
        float scalingFactor = Time.deltaTime;
        Vector2 mouseDelta = inputManager.inputActions.Player.CameraRotation.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        _cinemachineTargetPitch += -mouseDelta.y * cameraSensitivity * scalingFactor;
        _rotationVelocity = mouseDelta.x * cameraSensitivity * scalingFactor;

        // clamp our pitch rotation
        _cinemachineTargetPitch = ClampAngle(_cinemachineTargetPitch, -maxXRotation, maxXRotation);

        // Update Cinemachine camera target pitch
        cameraTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_cinemachineTargetPitch, 0f, 0f);

        // rotate the player left and right
        playerTransform.Rotate(Vector3.up * _rotationVelocity);
    }


wouldn't this mainly depend on the sensitivity of your mouse vs your joystick?

Yes, but the problem is that the rotation is faster in the build than in the editor (the sensitivity remains the same in both).

The issue here is the mouseDelta (assuming that it actually is the mouse delta) is already a frame dependent value. So you must not multiply mouseDetla with Time.deltaTime. Multiplying by deltaTime is a transformation from a time based value to a frame based value. So a speed in meters per second would be converted into meters per frame. Mouse delta input represents the change or the mouse position between two frames.
Vector2 mouseDelta = inputManager.inputActions.Player.CameraRotation.ReadValue<Vector2>();

_cinemachineTargetPitch += -mouseDelta.y * cameraSensitivity;
_rotationVelocity = mouseDelta.x * cameraSensitivity;
// [ ... ]

This should give you a constant result. Though note that this will not be true for WebGL builds because inside the browser you get an abstracted mouse delta which usually does not match the hardware mouse delta. You usually need a different sensitivity inside the browser. This is a known issue and may be related to how the mouse API works in browsers. There doesn't seem to be a consistent behaviour, even across browsers.
Especially for WebGL it's highly recommended that you include a sensitivity setting for your users and allow a large enough range.

But since the joystick input returns a -1 to 1 value, shouldn't I multiply the joystick input by delta time and leave the mouse input unmultiplied? (the mouseDelta returns both the joystick input and the mouse delta input, I should've named it better)

Multiplying by deltaTime is a transformation from a time based value to a frame based value. So a speed in meters per second would be converted into meters per frame .. no, it is exactly the other way round, it converts a value per frame into a value per second

The point probably still stands though as a mouse delta is in absolute pixel space -> the sensitivity depends on your screen/player resolution

@derHugo no, it is exactly the other way round, it converts a value per frame into a value per second. No, it's the way I explained it :) A velocity value may be given in units per second which is a time based value. We multiply it by Time.deltaTime to get a units per frame value which we need to apply this frame. That's the point.

@Bunny83 ah sorry ^^ I guess we interpreted this from different directions but meant the same
